# when calling the geocoder constructor in a thread the connection crashes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, object

I'm trying hardly to implement a geocoder in android in a Runnable class:
This is the way I did it:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);


                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        (int)(coord.getLat()), (int)(coord.getLon()), 1);

                if (list != null && list.size()>0 ){

                    Address address=list.get(0);
                     String result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();

                }
```

My class,Runnable is actually a thread that connects to a remote server and receives data from there using a buffer.

And here is my problem:

The connection with the server is or was quite good until I put the line with the geocoder inside my code.

Now once I've added the Geocoder lines this side of my connection with the server crashes!!!

Now I know for sure that is because of the geocoder because only today I've added it to my app and until now my app worked very well and the connection was strong....

Here is my entire code and if someone could tell how could I implement Geocoder in a better way please do:

```
public class ClientThread_special implements Runnable {

    int serverPort = 6500;
    private String serverIpAddress = "10.0.2.2";
    Coordinate coord;
    ObjectInputStream is;
    boolean stop = false;
    DBAdapter db;
    boolean t = false;
    int id;
    Context context;
    PrintStream strReturnedAddress;

    public ClientThread_special(DBAdapter db, Context context) {
        this.db = db;
        this.context = context;

    }

    public void run() {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);


        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverIpAddress, serverPort);

            is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            try {
                while (!stop) {
                    coord = (Coordinate) is.readObject();
                    System.out.println("Date de la clientul de monitorizare:"
                            + coord.getLat());

                    List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                            (int)(coord.getLat()), (int)(coord.getLon()), 1);

                    if (list != null && list.size()>0 ){

                        Address address=list.get(0);
                         String result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();

                    }
                    System.out.println("adresa returnata folosind geocoder:"
                            + strReturnedAddress);
```

....................................................

```
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }


            is.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

public void stop() {

        this.stop = true;

    }

}
```

From the server I'm reading some object.... If is neccesary other further details I'm here

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a `Log.v("EXCEPTION","message",e);` inside your IO try/catch block as mostly when `geocoder` fails throws an `IOException`. and that may help you as you'll know what exactly is going wrong. WHAT I FEEL is that geocoder sometime fails to return the address that corresponds to lat/long so check your lat/long and check for the list to NOT NULL then proceed in order to prevent the crash.like this ....`if (list.size()>0) address=address_found  ;  else address="unknow address" ; and proceed like this,`